# JavaScript put text in textarea within iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use JavaScript to put text in a text area within an iFrame?

index.html

```
<iframe src="http://othersite.com:3000">
```

within iFrame there is a textarea

```
<textarea class="inp" placeholder="Send message..."></textarea>
```

Is it possible to put text in it?

Comment: If the page hosting the iframe is not also served from `othersite.com` which seems unlikely given the name, then no, you cannot interact with the iframe page at all; same-origin policy prevents this for good security reasons.

Comment: If the `othersite.com` is listening for a message,then you can use this [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).It is a two-way communication,they must have code to listen for the message and insert it in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify HTML of a iFrame, the solution : have to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). If you can't modify code of "http://othersite.com:3000" it will be impossible.

If you can, try this :

Step 1 : send a message to iFrame when she is loaded

```
$('#iframe').load(function(){
    source = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
    source.postMessage('hi', 'http://othersite.com:3000');
});
```

Setp 2 : receive message on "http://othersite.com:3000" and modify textarea value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    if(e.origin === 'http://yourwebsite'){
      $('.inp').val('put your text here');
    }
  }, false)
}
```

I think it will be not work at the first time, read documentation and try but keep the same way :)
I hope it will be help you